# Display range of rows from first column with awk

Tags: awk

I have a table as shown below, here I just want to print all the `Emp_Name` from the first column starting from the second row.

```
Emp_Name    Position        Experience
Cara        Senior          12
Doc         Junior          6
Quinn       Lead            14
Cedric      Manager         18
Collen      Junior          8
```

I know that `awk '{print $1}'` will print the first column from the table but how to skip first row or field i.e. `Emp_Name` and print all the names from the second row to the last field? Here last field or row number could be any number (not known).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: `awk 'FNR > 1 { print $1 }' file` ?? (or simply `NR > 1` if you want to pass multiple files as input)

Comment: My bad Cyrus, I wanted to get all the employees name from the first column. e.g. Cara
Doc
Quinn
Cedric
Collen. Thanks, David I was looking for the same.

Comment: Don't describe your expected output in a comment **show** your expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not fully clear though, in case you want to skip only first row then try following.

```
awk 'FNR>1' Input_file
```

OR to print 1st column use:

```
awk 'FNR>1{print $1}'  Input_file
```

---

---

In case you do not know on which field `Emp_No` will come and you want to look for its column number from 1st row AND DO NOT want to print the same column from rest of the row then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t"
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     if($i=="Emp_Name"){
       val=i
       next
     }
  }
}
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     if(i==val){
       continue
     }
     else{
       value=(value?value OFS:"")$i
     }
  }
  print value
  value=""
}
'   Input_file
```

Comment: thanks, I was looking for the "awk 'FNR>1'" with { print $1 } option.

Comment: @learning, sure, give it sometime and you could select any answer out of all as correct answer too, cheers.